# Why does my compiler say that there is a semicolin missing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run this code and it says that there are no problems in my IDE, but my compiler says `"Error CS 1002: ; expected"`.

I can't find it?

```
using System;

namespace code
{

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Ask me anything!");

            string userQuestion = Console.ReadLine();

                string areYouABot = "I am not!";

                    if (userQuestion = "Are you a bot?");
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(areYouABot);


                    }


} 
}
```

Comment: `userQuestion = "Are you a bot?"` -- you should use `==` for comparisons: `userQuestion == "Are you a bot?"`. A single `=` is for assignments

Comment: Yeah I changed that but still I don't know why it says a semicolin is missing?

Comment: It seems like you actually have an extra semicolon.  After the "Are you a bot");   Perhaps that is confusing the compiler.  No semicolon on "if" lines.

Comment: You'd be surprised how effective formatting code can be for finding issues.  Try formatting your code.  That said, this is wrong: `if (userQuestion = "Are you a bot?");`.  An `if` statement needs a Boolean expression in the parentheses.  You have `userQuestion = "Are you a bot?"`, which isnt' a Boolean expression, it's a string assignment statement.  Also, by following it with a semi-colon, you are "completing" the conditional.  The following block of code 'Console.WriteLine(areYouABot);` will always run (since the IF is completed)

Comment: @xdestinty The compiler sees an assignment (a single `=`), and it expects that to be followed by a semicolon. However, the problem is not that you've got a missing semicolon, it's that you shouldn't have an assignment. The compiler can't read your *intentions*, sadly

Comment: I say @Flydog57 should add his response as an answer for the OP to mark as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace code
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Ask me anything!");
         string userQuestion = Console.ReadLine();
         string areYouABot = "I am not!";

         if (userQuestion == "Are you a bot?")
         {
            Console.WriteLine(areYouABot);
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

1. Put your class in your namespace.
2. If statements need booleans so change `=` to `==`
3. You don't put semicolons after if statements (or any loops) for the same reason you don't put one after namespace, class, or Main. They all are "wrapping" something instead of "doing" something. The exception being if the (if/loop) statement is "wrapping" only a single line. Ex. `if (userQuestion == "Are you a bot?") Console.WriteLine(areYouABot);`

If you would like any more explanation on any of these, let me know in a comment below.

Edited to include comments below.

Comment: Minor caveat: You can put a semikolon after a if, but most of the time (inlcuding thise time) beginners do it in error. Control sturctures govern the next block *or* everything to the next Semikolon, wichever comes first. And having a single-line governed by a if or loop can be usefull syntax.

Comment: To clarify @Christopher 's statement, since you only have a single line in your if-statement, you can remove the `{ }` from that and it will still perform as expected. However, I cannot think of any situation where you would want a semicolon directly after the if-statement. Instead, you would want something like ```if (userQuestion == "Are you a bot?")
         
            Console.WriteLine(areYouABot);
         ```

Comment: Your third point could use some work. First, it *is* legal to put a semicolon after a class in C#; it is not *required* but it is legal. (Why? Because it is required in C++, and C# was designed to be familiar and easy for C++ programmers to pick up.) But more importantly, we *do* put semicolons after `if` statements quite frequently. `if(x) M();` is an `if` statement that ends with a semicolon. The actual rule is: the consequence of an `if` is a *statement*, a block of form `{ statements }` is a *statement*, and such blocks do not end in a semicolon.